# Fibonacci sequence using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a list comprehension that will give out `Fibonacci` number until the number 4 millions. I want to add that to list comprehension and sum evenly spaced terms.

```
from math import sqrt
Phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
phi = (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2
series = [int((Phi**n - phi**n) / sqrt(5)) for n in range(1, 10)]
print(series)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

This is a sample code that works and I want to write similar code using list comprehension. Please do help.

```
a, b = 1, 1
total = 0
while a <= 4000000:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        total += a
    a, b = b, a+b 
print(total)
```

Comment: List comprehension implys that a list() to be generated. From your question, you do not need a list. So why do you need list comprehension?

Comment: Why would you want a list comprehension? It appears to me a generator would be more than adequate for this, or even just a *function* that sums the values.

Comment: @WongSiwei I just wanna know if I can place those values in a list with all those constraints.

Comment: @paxdiablo I was able to write a function but I just wanna have a list with all the values until the number reaches 4 million.

Comment: You probably can, but the last I checked, you might come to a memory error when the list got too big.

Comment: @WongSiwei Can't we use something like a cache along the way to do it. I just wanted to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no actual *list* required for what you need to do, it's a bit wasteful having a list comprehension. Far better would be to just provide a function to do all the heavy lifting for you, something like:

```
def sumEvenFibsBelowOrEqualTo(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    total = 0
    while a <= n:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            total += a
        a, b = b, a + b 
    return total
```

Then just call it with `print(sumEvenFibsBelowOrEqualTo(4000000))`.

If you really *do* want a list of Fibonacci numbers (perhaps you want to run *different* comprehensions on it), you can make a small modification to do this - this returns a list rather than the sum of the even values:

```
def listOfFibsBelowOrEqualTo(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    mylist = []
    while a <= n:
        mylist.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    return mylist
```

You can then use the following list comprehension to sum the even ones:

```
print(sum([x for x in listOfFibsBelowOrEqualTo(4000000) if x % 2 == 0]))
```

This is probably not *too* bad given that the Fibonacci numbers get very big very fast (so the list won't be that big) but, for other sequences that don't do that (or for much larger limits), constructing a list may use up large chunks of memory unnecessarily.

---

A better method may be to use a generator which, if you *want* a list, you can always construct one from it. But, if you *don't* need a list, you can still use it in list comprehensions:

```
def fibGen(limit):
    a, b = 1, 1
    while a <= limit:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

mylist = list(fibGen(4000000))                          # a list
print(sum([x for x in fibGen(4000000) if x % 2 == 0]))  # sum evens, no list
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is by its nature a parallel process; it's a process in which an input iterable is fed in, some function is applied to each element, and an output list is created. When this function is applied, it is applied to each element independently of other elements. Thus, list comprehensions are not suitable to iterative algorithms such as the one you present. It could be used in your closed-form formula:

`sum([int((Phi**n - phi**n) / sqrt(5)) for n in range(1, 10) if int((Phi**n - phi**n) / sqrt(5))%2 == 0])`

If you want to use an iterative algorithm, a generator is more suitable.